# Pytorch customized dataloader

Tags: pytorch, dataloader, pytorch-lightning

I am trying to train a classifier with MNIST dataset using pytorch-lightening.

```
import pytorch_lightning as pl
from torchvision import transforms
from torchvision.datasets import MNIST, SVHN
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, random_split


class MNISTData(pl.LightningDataModule):

    def __init__(self, data_dir='./', batch_size=256):
        super().__init__()
        self.data_dir = data_dir
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.transform = transforms.ToTensor()

    def download(self):
        MNIST(self.data_dir, train=True, download=True)
        MNIST(self.data_dir, train=False, download=True)

    def setup(self, stage=None):
        if stage == 'fit' or stage is None:
            mnist_train = MNIST(self.data_dir, train=True, transform=self.transform)
            self.mnist_train, self.mnist_val = random_split(mnist_train, [55000, 5000])
        if stage == 'test' or stage is None:
            self.mnist_test = MNIST(self.data_dir, train=False, transform=self.transform)

    def train_dataloader(self):
        mnist_train = DataLoader(self.mnist_train, batch_size=self.batch_size)
        return mnist_train

    def val_dataloader(self):
        mnist_val = DataLoader(self.mnist_val, batch_size=self.batch_size)
        return mnist_val

    def test_dataloader(self):
        mnist_test = DataLoader(self.mnist_test, batch_size=self.batch_size)
```

After using `MNISTData().setup()`, I gained `MNISTData().mnist_train, MNISTData().mnist_val, MNISTData().mnist_test` whose length are 55000, 5000, 10000 with type of torch.utils.data.dataset.Subset.

But when i call dataloader w.r.t `MNISTData().train_dataloader, MNISTData().val_dataloader, MNISTData().test_dataloader` I only get DataLoader with 215, 20, None datas in them.

Can someone know the reason or could fix the problem?

Comment: Where is the code that returns `215, 20, None`? BTW, there is no `return` in the `test_dataloader(...)`.

Comment: After correcting `return` of `test_dataloader()` I still have an issue.

Comment: `a = MNISTData()`
`a.setup()`
`b,c,d = a.train_dataloader(), a.val_dataloader(),a.test_dataloader()`
could you try above code and check the variables ?

Answer (score 1):

As I told in the comments, and Ivan posted in his answer, there was missing return statement:

```py
def test_dataloader(self):
    mnist_test = DataLoader(self.mnist_test, batch_size=self.batch_size)
    return mnist_test  # <<< missing return
```

As per your comment, if we try:

```py
a = MNISTData()
# skip download, assuming you already have it
a.setup()

b, c, d = a.train_dataloader(), a.val_dataloader(), a.test_dataloader()
# len(b)=215, len(c)=20, len(d)=40
```

I think your question is why the length of `b, c, d` are different from the length of the datasets. The answer is that the `len()` of a `DataLoader` is equal to the number of batches, not the number of samples, therefore:

```py
import math

batch_size = 256
len(b) = math.ceil(55000 / batch_size) = 215
len(c) = math.ceil(5000 / batch_size) = 20
len(d) = math.ceil(10000 / batch_size) = 40
```

BTW, we're using `math.ceil` because [`DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader) has `drop_last=False` by default, otherwise it would be `math.floor`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `test_dataloader` function is missing a `return` statement!

```
def test_dataloader(self):
    mnist_test = DataLoader(self.mnist_test, batch_size=self.batch_size)
    return mnist_test
```

---

```
>>> ds = MNISTData()
>>> ds.download()
>>> ds.setup()
```

Then:

```
>>> [len(subset) for subset in \
          (ds.mnist_train, ds.mnist_val, ds.mnist_test)]
[55000, 5000, 10000]


>>> [len(loader) for loader in \
         (ds.train_dataloader(), ds.val_dataloader(), ds.test_dataloader())]
[215, 20, 40]
```

Answer (score 0):

Others pointing out the fact that you are missing a `return` is the `test_dataloader()` is certainly correct.

Judging by how the question is framed, it seems you are confused about the length of a `Dataset` and a `DataLoader`.

`len(Dataset(..))` returns the number of data samples in your dataset.

whereas, `len(DataLoader(ds, ...))` returns the number of *batches*; and that depends of how much `batch_size=...` you requested, whether you want to `drop_last` batch etc. The exact calculations are provided correctly by @Berriel