# What's wrong with my subclass of pytorch's DataLoader? - Error: Too many open files

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

What is wrong with my subclass of `torch.utils.data.DataLoader`? After using this instead of the original, I get an error. The error is solved by setting `pin_memory` (in the superclass) to `False`.

This is the class (the actual class has a few more parameters which are all not used, for compatibility with my code):

```
class CustomDataLoader(torchdata.DataLoader):
    def __init__(self, dataset, batch_size, shuffle, 
                 collate_fn=None, pin_memory=False, num_workers=4, **kwargs):
        ''' Custom data loader to test how to subclass torchdata.DataLoader.
            '''
        super().__init__( dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=shuffle, collate_fn=collate_fn,
                          pin_memory=pin_memory, num_workers=num_workers, **kwargs)

    def __iter__(self):
        self.super_iter = super().__iter__()
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        next_batch = self.super_iter.__next__() 
        return next_batch, None, None
```

And here the start of the 150 lines long error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/util.py", line 300,  in _run_finalizers
    finalizer()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/util.py", line 224,  in __call__
    res = self._callback(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/util.py", line 133, in _remove_temp_dir
    rmtree(tempdir)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/shutil.py", line 725, in rmtree
    _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/shutil.py", line 633, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    onerror(os.scandir, path, sys.exc_info())
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/shutil.py", line 629, in _rmtree_safe_fd   
    with os.scandir(topfd) as scandir_it:
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '/tmp/pymp-n1e35f4z'
```

The code that raises the error uses a dataset that is currently not public, so I cannot use the same code here. Just looping over the dataset fails to reproduce the issue, however.

I've seen a few questions here asking something related, but usually the answer does not require to subclass `DataLoader` ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71744788/subclass-of-pytorch-dataloader-for-changing-batch-output) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69170854/pytorch-customized-dataloader)). More related could be this: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/too-many-open-files-caused-by-persistent-workers-and-pin-memory/193372, because setting `pin_memory` to `False` also helped in my case.

Are there any issues with my class above, that could lead to pytorch-internal issues with data loading? Or does it look okay?

---

Edit: Remainder of the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/util.py", line 300, in _run_finalizers
    finalizer()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/util.py", line 224, in __call__
  s res = self._callback(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/util.py", line 133, in _remove_temp_dir
    rmtree(tempdir)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/shutil.py", line 725, in rmtree
    _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/shutil.py", line 633, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    onerror(os.scandir, path, sys.exc_info())
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/shutil.py", line 629, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    with os.scandir(topfd) as scandir_it:
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '/tmp/pymp-n1e35f4z'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/util.py", line 300, in _run_finalizers
    finalizer()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/util.py", line 224, in __call__
    res = self._callback(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/util.py", line 133, in _remove_temp_dir
    rmtree(tempdir)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/shutil.py", line 725, in rmtree
    _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/shutil.py", line 633, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    onerror(os.scandir, path, sys.exc_info())
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/shutil.py", line 629, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    with os.scandir(topfd) as scandir_it:
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '/tmp/pymp-u0_3n68n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/resource_sharer.py", line 138, in _serve
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 463, in accept
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 609, in accept
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/socket.py", line 293, in accept
    fd, addr = self._accept()
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
Exception in thread Thread-534 (_pin_memory_loop):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/pin_memory.py", line 51, in _pin_memory_loop                                                                                      
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/resource_sharer.py", line 145, in _serve
    send(conn, destination_pid)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/resource_sharer.py", line 50, in send
    reduction.send_handle(conn, new_fd, pid)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 183, in send_handle
    with socket.fromfd(conn.fileno(), socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/socket.py", line 545, in fromfd
    nfd = dup(fd)
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
    do_one_step()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/pin_memory.py", line 28, in do_one_step
    r = in_queue.get(timeout=MP_STATUS_CHECK_INTERVAL)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 122, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/reductions.py", line 307, in rebuild_storage_fd
    fd = df.detach()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/resource_sharer.py", line 58, in detach
    return reduction.recv_handle(conn)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 189, in recv_handle
    return recvfds(s, 1)[0]
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 159, in recvfds
    raise EOFError
EOFError
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 244, in _feed
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
        cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/reductions.py", line 370, in reduce_storage                                                                                         
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 198, in DupFd
        return resource_sharer.DupFd(fd)
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/resource_sharer.py", line 48, in __init__
        new_fd = os.dup(fd)
    OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/util.py", line 300, in _run_finalizers
        finalizer()
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/util.py", line 224, in __call__
        res = self._callback(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/util.py", line 133, in _remove_temp_dir
        rmtree(tempdir)
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/shutil.py", line 725, in rmtree
        _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror)
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/shutil.py", line 633, in _rmtree_safe_fd
        onerror(os.scandir, path, sys.exc_info())
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/shutil.py", line 629, in _rmtree_safe_fd
        with os.scandir(topfd) as scandir_it:
    OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '/tmp/pymp-oyedwdyi'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 244, in _feed
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/reductions.py", line 370, in reduce_storage                                                                                         
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 198, in DupFd
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/resource_sharer.py", line 48, in __init__
    OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 244, in _feed
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/reductions.py", line 370, in reduce_storage                                                                                         
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 198, in DupFd
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/resource_sharer.py", line 48, in __init__
    OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
```

---

And then the very final part (raised within 'finally' after the error above):

```
Exception in thread Thread-535 (_pin_memory_loop):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/pin_memory.py", line 51, in _pin_memory_loop                                                                                      
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/pin_memory.py", line 28, in do_one_step                                                                                           
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 122, in get
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/reductions.py", line 307, in rebuild_storage_fd                                                                                     
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/resource_sharer.py", line 57, in detach
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/resource_sharer.py", line 86, in get_connection
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 502, in Client
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 628, in SocketClient
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/socket.py", line 232, in __init__
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]/train.py", line 545, in train
  File "[...]/train.py", line 248, in train_or_eval_epoch
  File "/src/group-orbit-cl/group_orbit_cl/data/sample_transformer.py", line 637, in __iter__
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 442, in __iter__                                                                                                    
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 388, in _get_iterator                                                                                               
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1043, in __init__                                                                                                   
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 121, in start
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/context.py", line 224, in _Popen
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/context.py", line 281, in _Popen
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 19, in __init__
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 65, in _launch
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]/train.py", line 1379, in <module>
  File "[...]/train.py", line 1376, in main
  File "[...]/train.py", line 639, in train
  File "[...]/train.py", line 687, in maybe_store_model
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 440, in save
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 315, in _open_zipfile_writer                                                                                                
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 288, in __init__
RuntimeError: File saved_models/4636315_0_mlp_ep-521.state_dict cannot be opened.
```

Comment: Why does `__iter__` return `self`? That seems like a bug. Probably don't muck with that method at all; set `super_iter` in `__init__` if you need it.

Comment: `__iter__` is, as far as I know, called when the iterator is restarted, such as at the start of a for-loop. Since I want to modify that simple subclass skeleton to add other things, that might also have to be reset when the iterator is restarted, I want to be able to override super's `__iter__`. If I am misunderstanding something, please elaborate!

Comment: Related, why I have it return self: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35657927/what-is-the-use-of-returning-self-in-the-iter-method

Comment: And, thank you for the format improvements!

Comment: The _end_ of the traceback would probably be more informative. Where exactly have you elided most of the 150 lines?

Comment: @tripleee , I've added the rest of the error output (it varies a bit every time). 
A large part of the error message comes from `python3.10/multiprocessing`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to fix this with `ulimit`.

Run `ulimit -n` to see the current file limit.

Then run `ulimit -n {larger_value}` to increase the limit. This should get you around the error.

You should also look at where files are being opened and try to either minimize the number of files opened or clean up open files. For example if your dataloader `__getitem__` implementation opens a file every time without closing the file, that can add up. It can also be a good idea to pre-process your dataset into a single file prior to training.

Comment: I have not tried this yet, however reading about this solution, the upper limit to ulimit is 4048, as opposed to the default of 1000 (I had 1003 files open at some point when the error happened). This does not seem to be a safe nor a scalable solution. What if I at one point am using more than two dataloaders in parallel, for whatever reason? I'll get close to the limit soon.

Comment: What I am asking is why might my subclassing cause that error, while the original DataLoader class seems to work fine.